# Execute multiple statement in single SQLITE

Tags: sql, sqlite, csv

I have 4 CSV file imported into SQLITE (`mastersuppress, ddsummary, rm5, excludelist`). All the file consist of 1 column (AccountNumber).

I manage to find the duplicate account number between 3 file and save the result in new CSV file named `Output` using this code :

```
select mastersuppress.Account
from mastersuppress
inner join ddsummary
on mastersuppress.Account=ddsummary.Account
union all
select rm5.Account
from rm5
inner join ddsummary
on rm5.Account=ddsummary.Account
```

Then I manage to delete the the AccountNumber from `Output` file the duplicate with account number in `excludelist` file using this second code :

```
delete   from Output
where    AccountNumber in
         (
         select  min(AccountNumber)
         from    excludelist
         group by
                 AccountNumber
         );

Select * FROM Output;
```

How to compile this 2 code into 1 code without need to create Output file in between the process. So the code look something like this

```
Delete   from ***FirstCodeResult***
    where    AccountNumber in
             (
             select  min(AccountNumber)
             from    excludelist
             group by
                     AccountNumber
             );

   //Display the result
```

Comment: Update your question and describe the input and output you want.

Comment: You appear to want to do some sort of set difference operation.  Please show some sample data what is happening here.

Answer (score 0):

I would phrase this using `except`:

```
select m.Account
from mastersuppress m inner join
     ddsummary ds
     on m.Account = ds.Account
union 
select rm5.Account
from rm5 inner join 
     ddsummary ds
     on rm5.Account = ds.Account
except
select el.AccountNumber
from excludelist el;
```

`except` and `union` remove duplicates.

Comment: This does not delete anything.